# Microsoft Azure : Can Automation Hybrid Worker be used to run scripts against computers on different accounts/subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In a case where you have several hundred VMs behind several different Azure accounts and a dozen or so different subscriptions, is it possible to use Hybrid Worker to run scripts against all of these VMs? If not, is there a service that accomplishes this in an Azure cloud environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start/stop a VM them you have to just make http post request with auth token, subscription id, resource group name, vm name.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/powerOff?api-version=2022-03-01
```

Also, you can use runbook to run scripts on vms but you can on;y use one worker for one automation account.

Refer [runbook docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker).

Comment: Thanks for the resource! The goal is to run powershell runbooks on all the VMs scattered across 2 or 3 accounts and any number of subscriptions. From what i have read, runbooks can work between subscriptions no problem. If an automation account is limited to one worker, does that mean it would be limited to working between two accounts?